# Glimpse in Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

Is there any way to get [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com) to work in Medium Trust?

If I set `<glimpse enabled="true"/>` in my web.config, I get a Security Exception:

```
   [SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionSet permSet, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand() +68
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckGrantSetHelper(PermissionSet grantSet) +57
   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.nCreateDynamicAssembly(AppDomain domain, AssemblyName name, Evidence identity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, PermissionSet requiredPermissions, PermissionSet optionalPermissions, PermissionSet refusedPermissions, Byte[] securityRulesBlob, Byte[] aptcaBlob, AssemblyBuilderAccess access, DynamicAssemblyFlags flags, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource) +0
   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder..ctor(AppDomain domain, AssemblyName name, AssemblyBuilderAccess access, String dir, Evidence evidence, PermissionSet requiredPermissions, PermissionSet optionalPermissions, PermissionSet refusedPermissions, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IEnumerable`1 unsafeAssemblyAttributes, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource) +198
   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.InternalDefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName name, AssemblyBuilderAccess access, String dir, Evidence evidence, PermissionSet requiredPermissions, PermissionSet optionalPermissions, PermissionSet refusedPermissions, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IEnumerable`1 unsafeAssemblyAttributes, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource) +125
   System.AppDomain.InternalDefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName name, AssemblyBuilderAccess access, String dir, Evidence evidence, PermissionSet requiredPermissions, PermissionSet optionalPermissions, PermissionSet refusedPermissions, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IEnumerable`1 assemblyAttributes, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource) +43
   System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName name, AssemblyBuilderAccess access) +42
   System.ComponentModel.Composition.MetadataViewGenerator..cctor() +257
```

From what I can tell, the error is similar to the one described [here](http://shazwazza.com/post/Using-metadata-with-MEF-in-Medium-Trust.aspx). Basically, MEF isn't able to do its trick of populating a meta-data instance implementing a particular interface when the app is running in Medium Trust.

Comment: I have a similar exception even app is run with <glimpse enabled="false"/> and <trust level="Medium"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately currently Glimpse requires Full Trust, you could file an [enhancement request](http://getglimpse.uservoice.com/forums/112413-general) with them, most features should be available in Medium Trust as well.

Comment: Yes I think this comment is right. Personally I haven't testing in non full trust environments but there is a fair amount of MEF being used during startup as well as some dynamic IL generation stuff as well.